# Height and Weight Picker Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, gesture

[image: Design]

I want to implement the functionality where user can pick height and weight by scrolling the pointer over the ruler. Basically I need to set the upper and lower bound of ruler to avoid over scrolling. And the value of movement of pointer should be displayed. So give me some idea to implement this feature.

Comment: You can use  `Sliders`  for this. Have a look : https://material.io/components/sliders/android#discrete-slider

Comment: I have read this. But thumb drawable can't be modified in slider.

Comment: up up I need it too, did you do it?